# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 (GET)

Tags: java, android, json, get, android-volley

i m using volley to send a request link with GET method to server to fetch a json

it works without any problem for most of android version for most of devices...

but it occurs unexpected error with a few tablets and makes this error

E/Volley(7696): [855] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for somesite/webservices/get_latest_records.php?thistime=19700101120000&city=newyork&model=XO Learning tablet&imei=3522222247251
10-01 16:19:59.047: W/System.err(7696): com.android.volley.ServerError
10-01 16:19:59.047: W/System.err(7696): at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:146)
10-01 16:19:59.047: W/System.err(7696):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)

i dont know why this Volley error occur? if it has problem why it works on most devices? and if it s a good resuest why it doesnt work on a few tablets????

```
requestDataFromServer("http://somesite/webservices/get_latest_records.php?thistime=19700101120000&city="+ URLEncoder.encode(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),"UTF-8") + "&model="+ URLEncoder.encode(Global.MODEL,"UTF-8") + "&imei=" + URLEncoder.encode(Global.IMEI,"UTF-8"));


            private void requestDataFromServer(final String url) {
            try {

                req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject JsonObj_Response) {

                                try {
                                    if (JsonObj_Response.getInt("success") == 0) {

                                    } else if (JsonObj_Response.getInt("success") == 1) {

                                        new InsertJSONToDB().execute(JsonObj_Response);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                            }

                        },

                        new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {

                            ex.printStackTrace();


                            makeToast("error");

                            }



        }
```

what should i do to solve this issue??

thanks in advance...

Comment: yes i found it. it was because of null pointer in some devices for imei. some devices doesnt have imei. by checking this value before send it the problem solved....

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. This was the request i send earlier which cause the 400 error.
http://myipHere:84/api/Test/NewRequest?apikey=SC:some_demo:d789b0c6a44fd4a9&assetid=AHU001&gender=female&issueid=**Wet Floor**.
look the space in *Wet Floor*.
although Browser restructure this as **Wet%20Floor** Volley doesn't.
So i had to add "%20" to give space and it worked. Hope this may help to someone...